# WatchOS background image stretching under table

Tags: tableview, apple-watch, watchos-3, wkinterfacetable

I a table view in my watch app which I am trying to put an image behind. This is what it looks like in the storyboard: [image: storyboard version]

and this is what I want, but when I run it on the simulator with a number more rows it seems to stretch the background image downward like so:

[image: bad stretching]
[image: more bad stretching on scroll]

Any ideas for I might be able to make it not stretch and be static in the background (not scroll with the table)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only thought would be to add the table to a group and set the background image of the group to whatever image you want. However, the image will be behind the table and not in front of it.

Comment: adding table to a group will result table not scrolling